# In google script two function having same name can be used in two different script tabs?

Tags: google-apps-script

On doing this the second myFunction is called why??? And the first one shows no response in the sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var SpSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var Name="Amit" 
  SpSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(Name);
}
```

==================================

```
function myFunction() {
  var SpSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
 var Name="Amit" 
  SpSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(Name);
}
```

Comment: Second function overwrite first func.

Comment: just like `var a = 0` `var a = 1` `console.log(a) // 1`

Comment: The real container is the project, script files are nothing else than the equivalent of "folders" to keep the code clear and readable.

Answer (score 2):

`myFunction` is overridden by the last `myFunction`. Here's an example

```js
function myFunction(){
  console.log('my function 1');
}

myFunction();

function myFunction(){
  console.log('my function 2');
}

myFunction();

function myFunction(){
  console.log('my function 3');
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: Does this mean that if we call our function any no of times it will call only the last function?

Comment: Yes it will call only the last function